# Arrows within nodes in tikz picture

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, arrows, tikz-arrows, draw

Hi you wonderful Tikzers! New here and having issues with a diagram. I want to make something like the picture below. [image: Crudely hand-drawn with Paint diagram of result desired]

I have copied and pasted some code and fiddled and this is what I currently get.

[image: first result]

My question is: how to get some little arrows in, where the "l"'s currently stand. I supply a minimal working example below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows, positioning, shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzstyle{every node}=[inner sep=1.7pt,anchor=center]
\tikzstyle{to_1}=[shorten >=5pt]
\tikzstyle{to_1i}=[shorten >=6pt]
\tikzstyle{to_2}=[shorten >=7pt]
\tikzstyle{to_3}=[shorten >=8pt]
\tikzstyle{from_1}=[shorten <=5pt]
\tikzstyle{from_1i}=[shorten <=6pt]
\tikzstyle{from_2}=[shorten <=8pt]
\begin{scope}
\draw [ultra thick] circle(1cm);
\draw [ultra thick] (0:4)--(180:4) (90:4)--(270:4);
\foreach \a
in {45,135,225,315}{
    \node at (90-\a:0.5cm) {\l};
        }

   \draw [very thick] circle(2cm);
   \foreach \A in {90,0,270,180}{
    \foreach \a in {30,60,90}{
                \draw [very thick] (\A+\a:1) -- (\A+\a:4);
            \node at (\A-\a+11.25:1.5) {\l};
       }
} \draw circle(4cm) (0:4)--(180:4) (90:4)--(270:4);

\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Any help is much appreciated! I really am new to all this :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, shapes.arrows}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
SA/.style = {shape=single arrow, draw,
             minimum height=5mm, minimum width=5mm,
             single arrow head extend=1.5mm,
             shape border rotate=#1,
             sloped
             }
                        ]
\foreach \a in {1,...,11}{\draw (0,0) -- (\a*360/12:4);}
\foreach \a in {1,...,3 }{\draw (0,0) -- (\a*90:4);}

\draw [ultra thick,fill=white] circle(1cm);
\draw [ultra thick] circle(2cm);
\draw circle (4cm);

\foreach \a/\r in {0/0, 90/0, 180/180, 270/0}
    {\path (0,0) -- node[SA={\r}] {} (\a:1cm);}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh, Wow! A million thanks, Zarko. Just like that! Kudos.